# why exactly doesn't logarithmic differentiation work here?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

As part of a larger problem, I have to differentiate $y^x$
so if we let $y=y^x$

we get $\ln(y)=x\ln(y)$

which means the differential is zero

alternatively, let $y=e^{\ln(x^y)}$

so $y=e^{x\ln(y)}$

which can be differentiated as follows

$y'=x^y\left(\ln(y)+y'\ \frac xy\right)$

which is $y'\left(1-{(x^y)}\ \frac xy\right)=x^{y}\ln(y)$

which means $y'=x^y\ln\left(\frac {y}{\left(1- {(x^y)}\frac{x}{y}\right)}\right)$

I apologise for not using MathJaX. I can't seem to get it to work for me

Comment: How can $y=y^x$?  This would be true if $x=1$, but otherwise....

Comment: well, the other way would be to write it as u=y^x, but unless I'm mistaken that would require multivariable calculus.

Comment: I suppose the question is what's the function here?  Or if it is to be implicit, where is the equation?

Comment: It might help to see at least some of the "larger problem" for context.

Comment: the entire question is differentiate x^x+x^y+y^x=a^b; I was able to differeniate all functions but this

Comment: What exactly is the problem? To avoid $y=y^x$ write $f(x) = y^x$ and from here $\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x} = \log(y) y^x$

Comment: I can't use partial differentials  @BreeZeriNoo

Comment: I fixed a few of the missing Mathjax problems. You should be able to fix the rest of them. Please do so so I can remove my down vote.

Comment: I'll try my best, thanks!

Comment: You can use implicit differentiation. If $f(x) = y^x = e^{x\ln(y)}$, then $f'(x) = (x\ln y)e^{x\ln(y)} = (\ln y + x(y'/y))e^{x\ln y} = (y^x)(\ln y + \frac{xy'}{y})$.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I'm aware of that. However, I'm curious as to why logarithmic differentiation doesn't work

Comment: Even setting aside that the derivative of $y^x$ is not the same thing as doing implicit differentiation on $y=y^x$, you did not solve for $y'$ correctly.

Comment: I corrected it now. My bad sorry

Comment: but when we're working with equations on the x-y plane isn't it assumed that it's of the form y=f(x)?

Comment: so the differential of f(x) is the differential of y

Comment: Logarithmic differentiation would involve taking $\ln|f| = \ln|y^x|$, not $\ln|y|=\ln|y^x|$. Again, differentiating the function $f(x) = y^x$ is **not the same** as doing implicit differentiation on the graph of $y=y^x$, which is what you attempted to do. That equation has solutions consisting of the positive $x$-axis (the points $(x,0)$ with $x\gt 0)$, the vertical line $x=1$, and the point $(0,1)$. There is no derviative on the vertical line or point, and you cannot do $\ln|y|$ on the horizontal line with $y=0$.

Comment: oh, OK. Thank you. In that case, why does exponential differentiation work? Is it as we're not changing the function?

Comment: Why does finding the derivative of the **actual function** you are trying to differentiate work, but finding the derivative of **something else entirely** give you the wrong answer? Because actually finding the derivative works to find the derivative, but finding something else entirely doesn't work. That's how the universe works.

Comment: "but when we're working with equations on the x-y plane isn't it assumed that it's of the form y=f(x)?" There are times when we set $y$ equal to a function of $x$ in order to make a graph on a plane with coordinates $x$ and $y$. The fact that someone asked you to differentiate $y^x$ indicates that this is not one of those times.

Comment: , thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Differentiating the function $f(x) = y^x$ (for some $y$ which is a function of $x$) is not the same thing as using implicit differentiation on $y=y^x$.

For example, if $y=e^x$, then $f(x)=y^x$ is the function $f(x)=(e^x)^x = e^{x^2}$; but $y=y^x$ gives $e^x=e^{x^2}$, which gives $e^{x^2-x}=1$, so the only values of $x$ that satisfy the equation are $x=0$ and $x=1$ and the graph of $y=y^x$ consists of exactly two points, $(0,1)$ and $(1,e)$.

The graph of $y=y^x$ consists of all points of the form $(x,0)$ with $x\gt 0$; the line $y=1$; and the line $x=1$. Indeed, all of these satisfy the equation: if $y=0$, then we need $x\gt 0$ for $y^x$ to make sense, and we get $0=0^x$; if $y=1$ then we get $1=1^x$, which holds for all $x$; and if $x=1$ we get $y=y^1$ which holds for all $y$. And these are the only solutions. If $y=0$, then we must have $x\gt 0$ (the positive $x$-axis); if $y\neq 0$, then $y^{x-1}=1$, so either $y=1$ and $x$ is arbitrary (the line $y=1$); or else $x-1=0$ (the line $x=1$ with $y\neq 0$).

Here, the derivative exists only on the positive $x$ axis and the line $y=1$. Of those, we can only use logarithmic differentiation for $y=1$, where we get
$\ln |y| = \ln|y^x|$, or $\frac{y'}{y} = \frac{xy'}{y}$, or $y'(x-1)=0$. This means $y'=0$, as expected.

The main problem with what you are doing is that you are trying to differentiate $f(x) = y^x$, but you are actually finding the implicit derivative for $y=y^x$, and there only for values with $y\neq 0$... where you just get $y'=0$ because of what that graph is.

You can use logarithmic differentiation for $y^x$ (leaving $y'$ indicated) if you set it up correctly. Setting $f(x)=y^x$, we have:
$$\begin{align*}
\ln |f(x)| &= \ln |y^x|\\
\ln |f(x)| &= x\ln|y|\\
\frac{d}{dx} \ln|f(x)| &= \frac{d}{dx}\left(x\ln|y|\right)\\
\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} &= \ln|y| + x\left(\frac{y'}{y}\right)\\
f'(x) &= f(x)\left(\ln|y| + x\frac{y'}{y}\right)\\
f'(x) &= y^x\left(\ln|y| + x\frac{y'}{y}\right)\\
f'(x) &= (\ln|y|)y^x + xy^{x-1}y'\\
f'(x) &= (\ln y)y^x + xy^{x-1}y',
\end{align*}$$
with last equality because $y^x$ is only defined for $y\gt 0$.

If you do it directly using $a^b=e^{b\ln a}$, we have:
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}y^x &= \frac{d}{dx} e^{x\ln y}\\
&= (x\ln y)'e^{x\ln y}\\
&= \left(\ln y + x\frac{y'}{y}\right) e^{x\ln y}\\
&= \left( \ln y + x\frac{y'}{y}\right)y^x\\
&= (\ln y)y^x + xy^{x-1}y',
\end{align*}$$
exactly the same result as before.

Comment: This explains a lot! Thanks a ton!